What does Zero of Hurewicz map mean?
So given a non trivial $\alpha\in\pi_n(X)$ where $h(\alpha)=0$ ( $h$ is the Hurewicz map  ). This means some $\partial\sum n_i\beta_i=\alpha$ exists ( abuse of notation ). It looks like we can fill $\alpha$ consistently which makes $\alpha\in\pi_n(X)$ trivial. I thought the $n_i\beta_i$ are not representable geometrically, then with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the base ring rules that case out. What exactly am I missing here?

Think of a genus 2 surface and a simple closed curve separating the "holes". Then it is not trivial in $\pi_1$ because it doesn't bound a disk, but it is trivial in $H_1$ because it bounds a puctured torus. I.e. being a contractible homotopy class basically means that the "bounding" region has to be a disk (in some sense), which is much stronger than being trivial in homology.

I see, that any such compact boundaries of a compact manifold that represent a class can be bounded by the manifold.
